# is there a more efficient way generate an array from another array with a little bit complex rule?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy

I am trying to compute a distance between an element and a starting point in an array.

Here is an array

[image]

assume the element (0,1) is a starting point which has the highest value currently.

a neighbors is an element around a specific point if they have one axis in common and different in another axis by 1 unit.

generally, a neighbor could be the top, bottom, left, right of a specific point, which is inside the array.

the task is to label every elements with a distance value indicate how far it is from the starting point (0,1).

```
ds = np.array([[1, 2, 1],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1]])

dist = np.full_like(ds, -1)
p0 = np.where(ds == 2)
dist[p0] = 0
que = []
que.append(p0)
nghb_x = [0, 0, -1, 1]
nghb_y = [-1, 1, 0, 0]

while len(que):
    x, y = que.pop()
    d = dist[(x,y)]
    for idx0, idx1 in zip(nghb_x, nghb_y):
        tmp_x = x + idx0
        tmp_y = y + idx1
        if np.any(tmp_x >= 0) and np.any(tmp_x < ds.shape[0]) and np.any(tmp_y >= 0) and np.any(tmp_y < ds.shape[1]) and np.any(dist[(tmp_x,tmp_y)] == -1):
            dist[(tmp_x,tmp_y)] = d + 1 # distance = distance(x) + 1
            que.append((tmp_x, tmp_y))

print('dist:')
print(dist)
```

the output

```
dist:
[[1 0 1]
 [2 1 2]
 [3 2 3]]
```

is as expected though, I would like to know if is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: By more efficient do you mean faster, using less memory or with less lines of code?

Comment: You want the Manhattan distance.

Comment: Can also build a graph and use `nx.shortest_path_length`.

Comment: You can just iterate every point and calculate the distance as the sum of the difference between the x coords, and the difference between the y coords, of the point and the target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calculating the [Manhattan distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) (the x-distance plus the y-distance) from a target point for each point.

You can use a numpy function to do it in one step, given the target coordinates and the shape of the array:

```
target = (0, 1)
np.fromfunction(lambda x,y: np.abs(target[0]-x) + np.abs(target[1]-y), ds.shape)
```

Result:

```
[[1. 0. 1.]
 [2. 1. 2.]
 [3. 2. 3.]]
```

Demo: https://repl.it/repls/TrustyUnhappyFlashdrives

Comment: There's little improvement to this answer, except perhaps to note that, depending on what you mean to use the resulting array for, you might be more efficient by just defining a function that gives you the distance for a pair of coordinates and only perform the computation for coordinates you actually use it for.

Comment: Or more directly: `np.abs(target[0]-np.arange(3))[:,None] + np.abs(target[1]-np.arange(3))`.  `fromfunction` seems to confuse beginners, making them think it is doing something profound.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55930785/putting-lambda-in-numpy-np-fromfunction-causes-typeerror