# Putting lambda in NumPy `np.fromfunction()` causes TypeError

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to understand NumPy `np.fromfunction()`.

following piece of code is extracted from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55929789/11074017).

```
dist = np.array([ 1, -1])
f = lambda x: np.linalg.norm(x, 1)
f(dist)
```

the output

```
2.0
```

is as expected.

when I put them together to use np.linalg.norm() inside np.fromfunction()

```
ds = np.array([[1, 2, 1],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1]])
np.fromfunction(f, ds.shape)
```

error shows up.

```
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
last) <ipython-input-6-f5d65a6d95c4> in <module>()
      2        [1, 1, 0],
      3        [0, 1, 1]])
----> 4 np.fromfunction(f, ds.shape)

~/anaconda3/envs/tf11/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py
in fromfunction(function, shape, **kwargs)    
2026     dtype = kwargs.pop('dtype', float)    
2027     args = indices(shape, dtype=dtype)
-> 2028     return function(*args, **kwargs)    
2029     
2030 
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

is it possible to put a lambda function(may be another lambda function) inside np.fromfunction() to do this job(get a distance array)?

Comment: Why did you expect that to work? What did you expect it to do?

Comment: Remember, when you post code that doesn't do what you want, we can see what it does, but not what it was supposed to do. You have to tell us that separately.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the error:

```
In [171]: np.fromfunction(f, ds.shape)                                               
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-171-1a3ed1ade41a> in <module>
----> 1 np.fromfunction(f, ds.shape)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py in fromfunction(function, shape, **kwargs)
   2026     dtype = kwargs.pop('dtype', float)
   2027     args = indices(shape, dtype=dtype)
-> 2028     return function(*args, **kwargs)
   2029 
   2030 

TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

`fromfunction` is a small Python function; there's no compiled magic.

Based on the shape you give, it generates `indices`.

```
In [172]: np.indices(ds.shape)                                                       
Out[172]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2]],

       [[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2]]])
```

That's a (2,3,3) array.  The 2 from the 2 element shape, and the (3,3) from the shape itself.  This is similar to what `np.meshgrid` and `np.mgrid` produce.  Just indexing arrays.

It then passes that array to your function, with `*args` unpacking.

```
function(*args, **kwargs)

In [174]: f(Out[172][0], Out[172][1])                                                
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-174-40469f1ab449> in <module>
----> 1 f(Out[172][0], Out[172][1])

TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

That's all it does - generate a n-d grid, and pass it as n arguments to your function.

===

Note also that you passed `ds.shape` to `fromfunction`, but not `ds` itself.  You could just as well written `np.fromfunction(f,(3,3))`.

What do you want your `lambda` to do with `ds`?  Clearly `fromfunction` isn't doing it for you.

===

With this `f`, the only that `fromfunction` can do is give it a `arange`:

```
In [176]: np.fromfunction(f, (10,))                                                  
Out[176]: 45.0
In [177]: f(np.arange(10))                                                           
Out[177]: 45.0
```

===

In the linked SO the lambda takes 2 arguments, `lambda x,y`:

```
np.fromfunction(lambda x,y: np.abs(target[0]-x) + np.abs(target[1]-y), ds.shape)
```

In that SO, both the question and answer, the `ds` array is just the source of the shape,  Target is (0,1), the largest element of `ds`.

Effectively, the `fromfunction` in the linked answer is just doing:

```
In [180]: f1 = lambda x,y: np.abs(0-x) + np.abs(1-y)                                 
In [181]: f1(Out[172][0], Out[172][1])                                               
Out[181]: 
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [2, 1, 2],
       [3, 2, 3]])

In [182]: np.abs(0-Out[172][0]) + np.abs(1-Out[172][1])                              
Out[182]: 
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [2, 1, 2],
       [3, 2, 3]])

In [183]: np.abs(np.array([0,1])[:,None,None]-Out[172]).sum(axis=0)                  
Out[183]: 
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [2, 1, 2],
       [3, 2, 3]])

In [184]: np.abs(0-np.arange(3))[:,None] + np.abs(1-np.arange(3))                    
Out[184]: 
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [2, 1, 2],
       [3, 2, 3]])
```

Comment: does "no compiled magic" mean fromfunction function is implemented in Python instead of C++?

Comment: @czlsws, it is easy to look at the code for functions like `fromfunction` (e.g [source] link on docs page).  Our error messages also show the relevant Python code.  All it does is call the function we provide.  It doesn't try to do any 'compiling' of our function.  Use something `numba` or `cython` if you want a compiled version of your function.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a 2 dimensional array, your function needs to take 2 inputs.

The docs of `np.fromfunction()` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html say "Construct an array by executing a function over each coordinate."

So it will pass the coordinates of each element of the array ((0,0), then (0,1) ... etc) to construct an array. Is this really what you are trying to do?

You could change the lambda to something like this, but it really depends on what you are trying to do!

```
f = lambda x, y: np.linalg.norm([x,y],1)
```